# Deallocate SKScene after modal transition

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have been creating a game in sprite kit using swift and have encountered a problem. I have two view controllers, each with one scene and one transitions to the other modally. This all works perfectly first time round, but then when i return to the first view controller and then go to the second again, i have using double the memory. This gives me the impression that nothing is being deallocated, but the objects are rather reallocated every time I transition to the scene. I ran the app in instruments and got the same result. In the below image i moved from one scene to the next, and then back to the first one again and yet it appears to reallocate the first scene and yet not clear any memory. As the dealloc method is unused now, i don't see how i can fix this. I will post the code to the first view controller below so you can have a look at it. Thanks a lot.

[image: Instument's recordings]

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class SelectionViewController: UIViewController {

var selectionScene:SelectionScene?
var currentRocketName = ""

@IBOutlet var playButton: UIButton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let selectionScene = SelectionScene.unarchiveFromFile("SelectionScene") as? SelectionScene {

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        selectionScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        selectionScene.viewController = self

        skView.presentScene(selectionScene)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(selectionScene, selector: "spinnerChanged", name: "spinnerValueChanged", object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(selectionScene, selector: "productBought", name: "ProductBought", object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(selectionScene, selector: "manageErrorInPurchase", name: "ErrorOccured", object: nil)

    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
}

@IBAction func playButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("moveToGame", sender: nil)
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.toRaw())
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.toRaw())
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func viewDidUnload() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(selectionScene)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(selectionScene)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "moveToGame" {
        let destController = segue.destinationViewController as GameViewController
        destController.rocketTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: self.currentRocketName)
    }
}

}
```

Both `selectionScene` and `currentRocketName` are passed to the viewController as soon as they are loaded into the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Swift yet, so I'll give you examples in Objective-C.

Create an `IBOutlet` for `skView`. When you are going to present another ViewController, remove `skView` from it's superview and nil it out:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Need to deallocate GameScene (if game is not paused)
    [self.skView removeFromSuperview];
    self.skView = nil;
    ....
}
```

Don't forget to add `skView` back to the ViewController's view, when ViewController is getting loaded:

```
if (!self.skView.window) {
    [self.view addSubview:self.skView];
}
```

To easily check if `SKScene` was deallocated or not, add this method to it:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"GAME SCENE DEALLOCATED");
}
```

Comment: Very thorough answer and with the exception of the dealloc method which cannot be used with iOS8 and swift, everything else looks like it will work perfectly.

Comment: I haven't met Swift yet :)

Comment: @JackC you probably want to use `deinit` instead of `dealloc` with Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH19

Comment: Crashes my application with the following: MTLTexture.m:643: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has one or more dimensions set that are zero or greater than the maximum allowed size.' I suspect, this is happening due to using auto layout and constraints established for the view. Is there a way to address it with auto layout? Cheers.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn your issue isn't related to this question, can you please create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

Turns out I had created a strong reference by having an SKScene instance as a delegate in another class. After declaring each property of SKScene type or UIView type as weak my issue was resolved:

```
weak var skScene:SKScene!
```